# Bootstrap 4 vertical image menu with image background

Tags: css, image, responsive

Hi there many thanks for stopping by, and lending a hand on the below:

I have built, in the old - before any responsive & BS-enabled website an image vertical menu, with a background image, an a series of div / buttons changing   upon hover.
I would like to reproduce this using BS4 and including this vertical image menu in a col-md-3 // col-md-9 boilerplate.

I have looked in all the solutions for resizing the background image through separate  classes / CSS to no avail, and not mentionning superimposing the button images with their related hover effect...

I would like to sow you the present situation (eg. non-responsive...) but as yet I can't put my sand box online , and obviously can't use JFiddle with my own images, o.. ? Would there be another public sandbox I could use to display the present state ?

as per the below:
[image]

I guess this would be my first & foremost question …:(

Many thanks,
JMB

Comment: Just for clarity, Do you want to keep the image or are you looking at redesigning the menu with bootstraps  buttons?

Comment: hi and thanks for your interest .
as a matter of fact,I would prefer each menu items to stay as a href items (maybe in the  form of   sprites vs :hover image alternatives...?).
Each item moves to the right  upon hover, without disrupting the overall "game" image in the background ( can't for the life of me remember the name of this children''s game....).
 many thanks
JMB

Comment: I am adding  the menu in a non-responsive state for reference in my sandbox:
[http://sandbox.jmbdev.com](http://sandbox.jmbdev.com)
Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your requirement fully but below I have added something on similar lines, see if its of any help

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<style>
.sidemenuitem:hover{
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.sidemenu{
width : 20%;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#3e4b5b), to(#DDD)) !important;
background: linear-gradient(to right, #3e4b5b, #DDD) !important;
}
.mainarea {
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#3e4b5b), to(#DDD)) !important;
background: linear-gradient(to right, #3e4b5b, #DDD) !important;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="container row">
<div class="sidemenu col-2">
 <div class="row"><div type="button" class="col-12 btn btn-primary sidemenuitem">1</div></div>
    <div class="row"><div type="button" class="col-12 btn btn-success sidemenuitem">2</div></div>
    <div class="row"><div type="button" class="col-12 btn btn-warning sidemenuitem">3</div></div>
    <div class="row"><div type="button" class="col-12 btn btn-info sidemenuitem">4</div></div>
    <div class="row"><div type="button" class="col-12 btn btn-danger sidemenuitem">5</div></div>
    <div class="row"><div type="button" class="col-12 btn btn-primary sidemenuitem">6</div></div>
    <div class="row"><div type="button" class="col-12 btn btn-success sidemenuitem">7</div></div>
    <div class="row"><div type="button" class="col-12 btn btn-info sidemenuitem">8</div></div>
    <div class="row"><div type="button" class="col-12 btn btn-danger sidemenuitem">9</div></div>
    <div class="row"><div type="button" class="col-12 btn btn-primary sidemenuitem">10</div></div>
</div>
<div class="mainarea col-10">
Lots Of content  Lots Of content  Lots Of content Lots Of content 
Lots Of content Lots Of content Lots Of content Lots Of content Lots Of content 
Lots Of content Lots Of content Lots Of content Lots Of content Lots Of content Lots Of content 
Lots Of content Lots Of content Lots Of content 
Lots Of content Lots Of content Lots Of content 
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HI RR1112 and thanks for your reply.
This is much helpful to understand the "respônsiveness" but, as you can see from my "sandbox", the issue I have with this menu is at least twofold:
- a background imaged div, which I would want to be responsive, whatever the parent container (in this case an col-md-3 div...), and within..
- menu items, clickable, made of images (background rather than inline, I guess...?), which would obviously also need to be responsive to fit within the parent above mentionned div ...as can be seen in my initial non-responsive menu / sandbox